# bash count files in path with wildcard and assign to a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

What am I missing?

I want to find out how many files match a given pattern in a directory and assign it to a variable.

If I type it all straight on the command line it works fine

```bash
ls /backups/system\ db\ files/temp/daily/backup_filename_202203*.tar.gz | wc -l
```

(n.b. the `*` is the date the backup was created, e.g. `01`, `02`, `03` etc.)

But as soon as I add it to my bash script it fails.

So far I have:

```bash
base_dir="/backups/system\ db\ files/temp" 
sub_dir="${base_dir}/daily"
filename_base="backup_filename_"
```

and I then try and run:

```
counter=$(ls ${sub_dir}/${filename_base_}202203*.tar.gz | wc -l)
```

or with quotes:

```
counter=$(ls "${sub_dir}/${filename_base_}202203*.tar.gz" | wc -l)
```

The first one fails as it tries to split it based on the whitespaces.
The second one doesn't expand the `*` to look for the wildcards.

I have tried just quoting some of it, e.g.

```
counter=$(ls "${sub_dir}/${filename_base_}"202203*.tar.gz | wc -l)
```

But again it ignores the wildcard.

I've been searching but for the life of me can't find a way to get the total number of matching files.

Comment: The variable `filename_base_` doesn't exist. You probably meant `counter=$(ls "$sub_dir/$filename_base"_202203*.tar.gz | wc -l)`. But even that's problematic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't escape the spaces when you already quoted them, otherwise the backslashes will be taken literally:

```
base_dir="/backups/system\ db\ files/temp"
```

should be

```
base_dir="/backups/system db files/temp"
```

Also why do you have `_` in `${filename_base_}` ?

Your last command should have *probably* worked if everything else was correct:

```
counter=$(ls "${sub_dir}/${filename_base}"202203*.tar.gz | wc -l)
```

---

Anyways, you [should not parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

Rather use `find`:

```bsh
find "${sub_dir}" -name "${filename_base}202203*.tar.gz" -printf '.' | wc -c
```

or an array:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob
files=("${sub_dir}/${filename_base}"202203*.tar.gz)
echo "${#files[@]}"
```

You need the `nullglob` option, otherwise the result will be `1` if no files match your pattern as the string is then taken literally.

Comment: cheers. I added the extra \ in to the string when it didn't work without them. I think I was getting myself confused going back and forth with typing it out in full and adding it to a variable.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is that your directory is not called `/backups/system\ db\ files/temp`, it is called `backups/system db files/temp`.  When you quote the string, you make the backslashes part of the string.  Since you quote the string, there is no need to escape the spaces. You also have the wrong spelling of the variable `filename_base` in a few places (with a trailing underscore).

You also don't need to use `ls` and `wc` to count the number of names matching a shell pattern.  Remember that filenames can have newlines in their names and that `wc -l` counts newlines, not filenames.

All you need to do to see how many matches there are to a shell pattern is to expand the pattern into an array or into the list of positional parameters and then see how long that array or list became.

Using an array with an example pattern:

```bsh
list=( "some/path to the/files"/*.txt )

count=${#list[@]}
```

Using the list of positional parameters:

```bsh
set -- "some/path to the/files"/*.txt

count=$#
```

In the `bash` shell, you will have to set the `nullglob` shell option using `shopt -s nullglob` to correctly handle empty directories (the pattern is usually left unexpanded if it does not match anything).

Without setting `nullglob`, you may instead test whether there were no matches using

```bsh
list=( "some/path to the/files"/*.txt )
count=${#list[@]}

if [ ! -e "${list[0]}" ] && [ ! -h "${list[0]}" ]; then
    count=0
fi
```

or, if you used the positional parameters,

```bsh
set -- "some/path to the/files"/*.txt
count=$#

if [ ! -e "$1" ] && [ ! -h "$1" ]; then
    count=0
fi
```

If the negated `-e` and `-h` tests are *true* for the first element in the resulting list, then the first element is not an existing file, and it is not a broken symbolic link. This means that there were no matches for the pattern.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, it makes a lot more sense now.